# How to use DDD for kernel debugging of a local Qemu virtual machine?

Tags: linux, debugging, qemu, gdbserver

I want to use [GNU DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) (gdb graphic shell) to debug Linux kernel, that is running (in some distro) inside qemu.

I have vmlinux image outside of Qemu, and launch Qemu with `-s -S`, so it acts like gdbserver (stops at start and waits for debuging commands).
Now, how to connect DDD to that gdbserver using local vmlinux image?

Should I just open image and tell gdb 'target remote'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically answered your own question - yes, use target remote gdb command in ddd to connect:

```
$ gdb qemuKernelFile
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
```

Answer (score 2):

With minor adjustments, you can use procedure described in great detail [here](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/debugging-arm-programs-inside-qemu/).

A picture from this tutorial:

[image]